# Knockout click binding with multiple parameters

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, binding

I'm confused on how the parameters are passed into the function from the HTML.

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: colorItem">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="click: $root.colorTest.bind($data, 'red', 'blue'), text: 'color'"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>


public colorTest(data, param1, param2) {   
    if (param1 == 'red'){
        // do something
    }
```

In the colorTest function, I expect 'data' to hold $data and 'param1' to hold the value 'red' and 'param2' to hold the value 'blue'.

However, $data always gets passed into the last parameter field. So in the colorTest function, data = 'red', param1 = 'blue', param2 = '$data'.

Is this how knockout works? $data is always passed into a function as the last parameter even if it is placed first in the HTML data-bind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .bind function isn't a part of knockout it's a javascript function, and the first parameter is always supposed to be the "this" context. So only the parameters after the first one get passed in as arguments. [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

You should modify your binding as follows:

```
click: $root.colorTest.bind($root, $data, 'red', 'blue')
```

Knockout calls the function with $data and $event, which get passed after the bound arguments.

Comment: thank you. This works. But do I need $data to be passed explicitly? As you state, Knockout auto sends $data and $event after the bound arguments (I saw this). So is it actually sending $data twice? Would it be better to use "... colorTest.bind($root, 'red', 'blue') and then capture the $data with the 3rd parameter in my function so that it looks like "public colorTest(param1, param2, data)" ?

Comment: how to access the property of the $data, in the colorTest function? is it $(data).Name? for example??

Comment: @Soya it's passed in as a function parameter, so its name is whatever you want it to be when you set up the function. It could be "z" if you bind with 2 parameters and use `function(x,y,z){ console.log(z.Name); }`

Answer (score 0):

Have the function in your viewmodel return a function.

```js
ko.applyBindings({
  colorTest: function(param1, param2) {
    return function() {
      console.log('param1 is ' + param1 + ' and param2 is ' + param2);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<button data-bind="click: colorTest('red', 'blue')">Color (click me!)</button>
```